# Como Selecionar apenas as 5 melhores empresas por país?

Tags: python

tenho uma planilha com as seguintes infos, `Year    Month   Country Advertiser_ID   Industry    Clicks  Displays    Client_Sales    Client_Revenue`.

quero selecionar as 5 melhores industrias baseado no client_sales por país

```
Soma_Valor3 = arquivo.groupby(['Country', 'Industry']).sum().groupby(level=[0]).cumsum() 
Soma_Valor3 = Soma_Valor3.sort_values(by=['Country','Client_Sales'], ascending=False).groupby('Country').first()

print(Soma_Valor3)
```

fiz assim e consegui pegar a melhor industria de cada país, porem nao consigo de jeito nenhum selecionar as 5 melhores de cada país. alguem pode me ajudar? obrigado!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Utilizando o pandas:

```
df.groupby(['Country','Industry']).Client_Sales.sum().groupby('Country').nlargest(5)
```

Caso deseje agrupar por anos e meses:

```
df.groupby(['Country','Industry','Year','Month']).Client_Sales.sum().groupby(['Country','Year','Month']).nlargest(5)
```

Comment: valeu demais!! tinha tentando usar o nlargest mas nao estava acertando a posição! obrigado!

Comment: e se eu quiser fazer a mesma questao porem limitar apenas para o ano de 2021?

Comment: Desse modo vc consegue filtrar o dataframe de acordo com o valor de uma coluna:
`df[df['Year']=='2021']`

A linha de  código que vc precisa ficaria assim:
`df[df['Year']=='2021'].groupby(['Country','Industry','Year','Month']).Client_Sales.sum().groupby(['Country','Year','Month']).nlargest(5)`

 Caso tenha solucionado teu problema, favor marcar resposta como aceita ;)